# Pushing Stack Exchange Profile To Other Accounts

Tags: support, linked-accounts

My global stack exchange profile is the way I want it. Can I push this profile to my other accounts?

Comment: What global Stack Exchange profile? There's no information in it at all.

Comment: @ChrisF Maybe he wants a black account. `:-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your global Stack Exchange site is not editable, and it is taken from the oldest Stack Exchange account you have. In my case, that is *Stack Overflow*; in your case, it is [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/36906/user36906).

[image: screenshot]

Just edit your oldest account, which is the one indicated in your global Stack Exchange account, and push those changes to your other accounts.

Anyway, you didn't put information that is visible to other users, in your account. None of your accounts shows anything different from the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yep!  When you click "edit" on your profile page, you have this nifty button:

[image]

Comment: He is referring to [his network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/918254).

Comment: @kiamlaluno Oh, my mistake!  I assume this would still work (as long as he found the profile that looks the same as his network profile and did this).  +1 to yours as it clearly states that.

Answer (score 2):

The global Stack Exchange profile inherits from your oldest Stack Exchange profile and isn't editable by itself far as I know.

A site-specific Stack Exchange profile has a "Copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts" button at the bottom of the "Edit Profile" page that you can use to replicate your profile on one site across your other accounts. From your profile, click "edit" and you should see it below the "Save Profile" button.

Comment: @ Anna-lear : just for curiosity, but if I press "Sync with oldest account" it Sync also the reputation points and the badge or only the information "About me"?

Comment: @Filippo1980 Only the stuff in "About me". Reputation points and badge information are updated automatically on their own schedules.